# Getting the correct encoding for strings and csv-files in Python

Tags: python, encoding, csv

I'm using mechanize in Python to grab some data from a website and send it new data.

The thing is that the site is in French, so I get question marks in a diamond shape (�) instead of various characters such as éÉÀàùÙîû and others.

I tried looking around on Google and StackOverflow and found various answers that didn't fix my problem. I've seen answers recommending trying one of the following lines:

```
myString = éÀî

myString.encode('latin-1')
myString.encode('iso-8859-1')

unicode(myString, 'iso-8859-1')
```

but none of those seem to work.

The two cases where I need this are when I read a csv file with accents and with hardcoded strings containing accents. For instance, here's what a line in the csv file looks like (actually ';' is the separator):

```
Adam Guérin;myemail@mail.com;555-5555;2011-02-05
```

The 'é' looks fine, but when I try to fill a textField on the website with mechanize and submit it, the 'é' now looks like '�' on the actual website.

**Edit:**

This is my code for reading the data in the csv file:

```
subscriberReader = csv.reader(open(path, 'rb'), delimiter=';')
subscribers = []

for row in subscriberReader:
    subscribers.append(Subscriber(row[0], row[1], row[2]))
```

Then I send it to the website using mechanize:

```
self.br.select_form('aspnetForm')

self.br.form['fldEmail'] = subscriber.email
self.br.form['fldName'] = subscriber.name
self.br.form['fldPhoneNum'] = subscriber.phoneNum

self.br.submit()
```

I tried various ways to encode the characters, but I guess I'm not doing it correctly. I'll be glad to try anything that gets suggested in the answers / comments.

As for the website, it doesn't specify which encoding it is using in the header.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Try using unicode strings f.e. str_ = u"éÀî"

Comment: @Lanaru For this project I'm using 2.7.2.

Comment: @Wyseck I just tried and it doesn't work. I had already tried unicode(myString, 'iso-8859-1') and other encoding types, but I forgot to put it in my question.

Comment: @Adam Pretty sure code like `myString.encode('latin-1')` only works for Python 3. Unicode handling works quite differently in Python 2.7

Comment: It might sound silly but it doesn't look like a python problem. It looks like you have a problem with encoding on your website. Are you sure that the site's encoding is correct? Can you see these french characters on your website?

Comment: @Wysek +1.  If the browser renders the text with � instead of French characters then most likely the declared character encoding of the documents there is inconsistent with the actual data.  It will mislead your mechanize client if that is happening.

Comment: @Wysek I'm not the one making the website, so I'm not a 100% sure what I'm going to say is correct, but the problem probably doesn't come from the website since I can fill the textfields manually with accents and the data shows just fine in the pages generated from it. Also, the csv file that contains accents is generated from that same data when I click a "save data as csv" button on the site. It's unlikely that the website would have an encoding problem since everything works when I enter data manually. Thanks for asking, though!

Comment: How are you reading the data from the page? The problem is that it's coming in as a string of bytes, which you need to *decode* from UTF-8 to Unicode.

Comment: can you see the correct text in a browser? What character encoding it reports? Does the server send a [correct character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)

Comment: @Lanaru: Yes, Unicode has been revamped for Python 3, but the `.encode()` method still exists in Python 2, for Unicode objects.

Comment: @Lanaru: Actually, I misspoke, it seems that `.encode` and `.decode` both exist for normal `str` objects in Python 2.

Comment: @chepner At the moment I'm reading the csv file that is generated when I click on the "generate csv from data" button on the website. With that data, I try to fill out textfields for every row in the csv using Mechanize. I don't know where the encoding might be different

Comment: Showing how you're reading the csv file and how you're writing it would be a lot more useful then some encoding and decoding on a string literal that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @Wooble I'll post the code snippet when I get back home, but I think the string literal is related because I tested it with a string literal as well and got the same result as with the csv file, so I thought by solving this it would also solve the csv problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you mentioned that you want to place literals into your code. To do so, you need to tell Python what encoding your script file has. You do this with a comment declaration at the beginning of the file (I'll assume that you're using `latin-1`).

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
myString = u'éÀî'
```

Second, you need to be able to work with the string. This isn't mechanize-specific, but covering a few basics should be useful: first, `myString` ends up being a unicode object (because of the way the literal was declared, with the `u''`). So, to use it as a Latin-1 encoding, you'll need to call `.encode()`, for example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(myString.encode('latin-1'))
```

And finally, when reading in a string that is encoded (say, from the remote web site), you can use `.decode()` to decode it into a unicode object, and work with it from there.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    myString = f.read().decode('latin-1')
```

Comment: to show that there is no relation between source and file character encodings you could use different encodings for each. You answer doesn't cover [how to get a character encoding of a HTML file sent over http](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)

Comment: You could use `'wb'` mode to write bytes to a file and *`'rb'`* to read bytes.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: In my tests, reading and writing without the 'b' flag works just as well. Do you know why this is?

Comment: it can't work in your tests. You use 'w' for reading. In Python 2 the difference between 'r' and 'rb' is only in how line endings are processed e.g., on Windows 'r' mode converts all '\r\n' on disk to '\n' in Python strings. In Python 3 'rb' produces bytes, 'r' - Unicode strings

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm starting to think that I don't have the same encoding as the webpage I'm sending the data on, but I don't know how to see what encoding it is using

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Right, that was a typo, sorry.

Comment: @AdamSmith: the web server should include a header or a meta tag that specifies the encoding. If it doesn't, it's broken IMO.

Comment: @Wooble I don't see the encoding when looking at the page source. Is there a way to find it or would there be a list of the encoding types I should be trying first? I'm guessing iso-8859-1 or latin-1 would be what I need from what I've read, but I don't know much about encoding. I'd really like to be able to get the accents working as it is primarily used for people's names.

Comment: @AdamSmith: It may be included as an HTTP header. If you have Google Chrome, you can use its [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) to view the HTTP headers.

Comment: Actually, it looks like mechanize itself reads the header and should be decoding things for you, from a quick browse of the source.